# Python3: Accessing func inside func inside class

Tags: python-3.x, class

I'm playing around and testing data structure and noticed you could print a list inside a class or a def function if you do class.list[0] or def.list[0], so I tried seeing how deep it could go and adding func inside func inside the class but instead of my expectation to just add more dots to the end of the value to chain them, it seems it doesn't work past 1 value.

```
class player:
    def __init__(self, name, spec):
        self.name = name
        self.spec = spec

    var1 = ('A1','A2')

    def def1():
        defA = "printed defA"
        def def2():
            defB = ('B1','B2')

print(player.def1.def2.defB[0]) #Doesn't work---

print(player.var1[0]) #Works fine---
```

In this case, would there be a way to print (or anything else) to the values nested deep in there? What would the address of this value be?

Comment: They're called functions, not defs...

Comment: Noted, and edited. Thanks.

Comment: Names go away after their blocks are exited.